# ActiveRecord grouping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this query in a `project model`:

```
report = self.reports.group(:key_id)
report.select('key_id, count(*) as count')
```

What do I need to add in order to get another column (`level`) from `reports` table?

I tried adding my column to `select` but that means that I have to group it as well and I only want to get the unique records by `key_id`

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output you want? The rule that any field selected in a grouped_by query must appear in _either_ in the grouped_by expression or within an aggregate function is fundamental to SQL.

Comment: Outpout: `[#<Report id: nil, key_id: 34>, #<Report id: nil, key_id: 14>..` thats what I get now, and I would like to get the `[#<Report id: nil, key_id: 34, level: 1> #<Report id: nil, key_id: 14, level 3>..` and only the key_id should be unique

Comment: What if you also have (say) `key_id: 34, level: 2` in your database? How would it select whether to show the `level: 1` record or the `level: 2` record?

Comment: The thing is that I am doing a count on the records and I would like to check how many unique `keys` have level < 10, or level < 20 or level < 30

Comment: If you only show one record per key_id, then how can you count them? You need to either group by key_id AND level and then count the results or you need to use an aggregative function on level.

Comment: But if I group by level, it will take only unique rows.

Comment: See answer for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include information about another field, then you have to include that field in the `group` expression or as part of an aggregate field. That's a fundamental aspect of SQL.

For example, if you want to count the number of occurrences of various values of `level` associated with each `key_id` then you can add a `count(level)` column. The aggregation field can get arbitrarily "fancy", such as counting up the number of occurrences of `level` within various bands as you've mentioned in your comment.